# How can I determine what mode the editor is in and when it changes?

Tags: visual-editor

I need to determine if the page/post editor is in Visual or Text mode. I also need to determine when this changes.

Does WordPress provide some kind of functionality for doing this? I am writing some JS that requires this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. To determine what mode the editor is currently in, you can use the `getUserSetting('editor')` in JavaScript, which returns either "html" or "tinymce".
2. To determine when the editor mode is switched, you can use the jQuery `click` event handler on the `#content-tmce` and `#content-html` elements, which are the editor type switching buttons:

   jQuery( '#content-tmce' ).click( function() {
       // Visual editor selected
   } );

   jQuery( '#content-html' ).click( function() {
       // Text editor selected
   } );

Bear in mind that these click events will always be triggered when you click on the buttons; when you click on the "Visual" button for example, the event will be triggered regardless whether the current mode is "Visual" or "Text". If you need to, you could easily tackle that by storing the previous state yourself.

Comment: Quick and dirty, but it will probably work. I'm going to give it a try. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: It is a little quick and dirty, but then again, that's how WordPress actually handles the Visual Editor modes itself. It's the prettiest way available, I believe. By the way, if it works, please mark the answer as "Accepted".

Comment: Yeah, I intended on accepting the answer. Seems to be what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could check tmce-active:

```
var editor = $('.tmce-active').val() != '' ? 'Text' : 'View';
```